Were we all intuitively misled into thinking that the universe has a 'speed' of expansion?
Universe has not even once had a speed of expansion but rather an acceleration. The thing is that since at small scales this acceleration is not noticiable it approaches a 'constant speed' given by the Hubble constant but if you remove the negiciable part you always have an acceleration rather than a constant rate of expansion

It has a speed of expansion, it's just proportional to distance away. That makes an exponential distance curve which is infinitely differentiable (exponentials are in $C^{\infty}$) if I'm not mistaken.

There is a rate of change $\dot a$ in the scale factor $a$, that one could pretty naturally call the speed of expansion

Even in the earliest models of an expanding universe the speed at which a particular galaxy was moving away was proportional to its distance, so there never was a single "speed" of expansion. The earliest models made the simplest assumption that the Hubble parameter did not change over time, but the Hubble parameter is best described as a "rate" of expansion rather than a speed.
The data points available at that time (1920s) were sparse and relatively nearby, so it made sense to start with the simplest model. In the modern era, as more data became available from more distant galaxies, it has become apparent that the Hubble parameter does change over time. The Hubble expansion model is a very empirical model (as far as we know, there are few theoretical constraints on the model) and its details will continue to be adjusted as a greater volume of more precise data becomes available.
